# Unable to click sub menu with Link attribute in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium webdriver. My website has a Menu button with further sub menus. The sub menu buttons can be accessed by either hovering over the Menu button or by clicking it. I have tried every combination but haven't been successful as of now.The source code is:

```
div class="divAPOAppMenu">
<ul id="projectDashboardMenu" class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-arrows">
   <li>
   <li class="">
   <a class="sf-with-ul" href="#">Manage Assessment</a>
   <ul style="display: none;">
   <li>
       <a id="btnAddAssessment">
       <img style="height: 20px; width: 20px; float: left; margin-right: 5px; border: none;" src="../../Images/AddIcons.png" alt="">
       New Assessment
       </a>
       </li>
```

I am trying to click the sub menu with the text "New Assessment" using:

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
WebElement moveToManageAssessmnt = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Assessment"));
action.moveToElement(moveToManageAssessmnt).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Assessment"))).click().perform();
```

This is not working out. 
I have also tried using:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Assessment")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Assessment")).click();
```

I am at my wits end on how to proceed and have no guidance available. Can someone please suggest me how to click the sub menu button?? Any sort of help will be highly appreciated!! Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
Actions mouseAction = new Actions(driver);
    mouseAction.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Assessment")).perform();
    mouseAction.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Assessment")).click().perform();
```

Comment: Thank you so much !
this worked. Also i had to add an explicit wait. Thanks for the help !!! :)

Comment: Accept the appropriate answer, because it will help others

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//ul[contains(@id, 'projectDashboardMenu')]/a[contains(text(), 'Manage Assessment']").click();
```

Comment: Thanks Mystia for the input. On a different note, can you please tell me if there are some good tutorials for locating Xpath cause i havent yet understood the concept fully !!

Comment: @Cerberus there is an add-on called firepath , which can be useful to find xpath.

Comment: Thanks Shantanu!
i am currently using Xpath Checker on Firefox.
i wanted to gain a more in depth knowledge on Absolute and relative xpath along with the Syntax. So far the material i have come across hasnt been much of a help !

Answer (score 0):

What you have just learned (unintentionally) is that Selenium will not (by default, there are workarounds you can google) interact with a `WebElement` that is not visible to the user. So... you can't click the submenu until you expose it with a hover. I wrote a function that hovers an element to take care of the first part.

```
public static void hoverElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element)
{
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
}
```

Once you do the hover, you should be able to click the desired element.

```
hoverElement(driver, driver.findElement(By.linkText("Manage Assessment")));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Assessment")).click();
```

Comment: oh right !!
Damn ! This should have been obvious to me !!
this is common sense !!
thanks a lot Jeff ! : )